# How can the strongest loop invariant be found for this code?

Tags: validation, formal-verification, loop-invariant, proof-of-correctness

I am trying to come up with a loop invariant for the following while-loop, but am having some trouble.

After the loop invariant is decided on, I would like to put together a proof tableau and show all intermediate assertions

```
ASSERT(k >= 0)
{i = 1;
 sum = 1;
 while (i <= k) { 
     sum = sum + 2*i + 1;
     i = i+1;
 } //end-while
}
ASSERT( sum == (k+1)*(k+1) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INV(1) = {sum == (n+1)*(n+1)}  
INV(2) = {0<=n<=k}
```

sum = 1 works for n = 0
Now try to prove that it does work for n+1 (if true for n), until n reaches k (in your case, my `n` is your `i`)

Answer (score 0):

Note that when it exists the loop the value of `i` is `k+1`, that is, a good invariant seems:

```
INV(1) = {1 <= i <= k+1}

INV(2) = {sum == i*i}
```